# Parsing a string into typedef structure in C

Tags: c, debugging, parsing

How do I parse a string from a file which contains characters and numbers into a typedef structure.

Those 2 lines are the example of data which needs to be parsed:

```
Pebbles Flintstone4Female
Bam-Bam Rubble3Male
```

First is name, then space and followed with the surname, then age and gender.

Name, Surname, Age and Gender are parts of typedef which this needs to be stored.

There are a total of seven string like those two above stored in the .txt file.

How do I write a correct buffer to separate the string?

This is what I've got so far

```
sscanf(buffer, "%[^ ]%*[^1234567890]%d%s", buff_name, buff_surname, buff_age, buff_gender);
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly and I cannot access any information about it.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting any errors? What is your expected result, and what are you seeing?

Comment: Did you open the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Always check the return value from `sscanf()` and its relatives.
2. Do enable compiler warnings.  A good compiler would tell you about the next issue:
3. Do not suppress the assignment using the `*` in `%*[0-9]` when you want the surname read.

Note that your `sscanf()` line doesn't use the data structure you mention.  However, this sample code does:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct who
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int  age;
    char gender[7];
} who;

int main(void)
{
    const char *data[2] = 
    {
        "Pebbles Flintstone4Female",
        "Bam-Bam Rubble3Male",
    };
    const char *fmt[2] =
    {
        "%[^ ]%*[^1234567890]%d%s",
        "%[^ ]%[^1234567890]%d%s",
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            who buff;
            int n;
            if ((n = sscanf(data[j], fmt[i], buff.name, buff.surname, &buff.age, buff.gender)) != 4)
                printf("Oops: format \"%s\", n = %d: %s\n", fmt[i], n, data[j]);
            else
                printf("Format \"%s\": data %s: %s %s %d %s\n",
                       fmt[i], data[j], buff.name, buff.surname, buff.age, buff.gender);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Oops: format "%[^ ]%*[^1234567890]%d%s", n = 3: Pebbles Flintstone4Female
Oops: format "%[^ ]%*[^1234567890]%d%s", n = 3: Bam-Bam Rubble3Male
Format "%[^ ]%[^1234567890]%d%s": data Pebbles Flintstone4Female: Pebbles  Flintstone 4 Female
Format "%[^ ]%[^1234567890]%d%s": data Bam-Bam Rubble3Male: Bam-Bam  Rubble 3 Male
```

If you compile with a string literal for the `sscanf()` format, GCC will warn you about the problem:

```
td.c: In function ‘main’:
td.c:23: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘char *’
td.c:23: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 5 has type ‘int *’
td.c:23: warning: too many arguments for format
```

The code above with different format strings can't give you that warning.

The format strings should be modified to avoid buffer overflows, too:

```
"%19[^ ] %19[^0-9] %d %6s"
```